# Google Play Games Services for Web - How can I search for players by gamerId?

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

I am developing a turn based web game using Play Games Services for Web. According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/turnBasedMatches/create), I can invite other players when a user creates a match setting the `invitedPlayerIds` property in `turnBasedMatches.create`. The problem is that I am not able to implement any player selection method (`players.list` always returns an empty list, no matter if I look for `connected` or `visible` states).

Now that Google has implemented [Gamer ID](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2954594?hl=es-419), is there any API to look for players by `gamerId` in the same way that the Play Games Android app lets the user find players and get their `playerId` to invite participants to the match? Or is there another way to look for players (email, contacts,...)?

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177641/how-to-access-google-play-games-gamer-id) if it can help you.

Comment: I had already read that one. It is about how to display the logged in user's id. What I am asking is how to search for certain users using their gamer ids and get their player IDs so I can start a match with them, not only with random players.